# Maintain offset when reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

I'm trying to reload a single tableViewCell but it scrolls to the top every time I do it... I'm not adding nor deleting cells, I just want to change the color of the selected cells.

This is what I do in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
SMPChoiceViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChoiceCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
SMPChoice *choice = self.choices[indexPath.row - 1];
cell.choiceTextLabel.text = choice.text;

if ([self.selectedChoices indexOfObject:choice] != NSNotFound) {
  cell.choiceTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
} else {
  cell.choiceTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

And this is what I do in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
if ([self.selectedChoices indexOfObject:choice] != NSNotFound) {
  [self.selectedChoices removeObject:choice];
} else {
  [self.selectedChoices addObject:choice];
}

CGPoint offSet = [tableView contentOffset];

[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView setContentOffset:offSet animated:NO];
```

But it just jumps, any suggestion?

P.S
I followed this thread but it didn't solved my question [Calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths removes tableView contentOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112013/calling-reloadrowsatindexpaths-removes-tableview-contentoffset)

Comment: Try UITableViewRowAnimationNone and remove [tableView setContentOffset:offSet animated:NO];

Comment: Hi Sathya... It still scrolls to the top and now it doesn't have that nice fading effect hehehe :'(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I had this same issue and couldn't find the answer anywhere.

After `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, the tableView determines its offset using the estimated heights given in `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`. So unless the value you return there is accurate, implementing it will cause your tableView's offset to change after the reload. I unimplemented `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and the problem was fixed.

Comment: The docs state: _"Return UITableViewAutomaticDimension if you have no estimate"_ in `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should return that instead of not implementing it.

Un-implementing the method causes my cells to give an inaccurate height

Comment: @Gee.E UITableViewAutomaticDimension was introduced in iOS 8. So if you don't have to support anything before iOS 8, then yes, you should use UITableViewAutomaticDimension. I'm not sure why unimplementing the method doesn't work for you though.

Comment: @Gee.E even returning UITableViewAutomaticDimension is just a slight improvement.  The TableView still jumps to a different position.

Comment: Yep, UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not doing it for me. ...and neither is not implementing the method.

Answer (score 17):

Because for some mysterious reason the table view determines the new offset after reloading some cells using the estimated row height you want to make sure the `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` returns correct data for cells that have already been rendered. To accomplish this you can cache the seen row heights in a dictionary, then use this correct data (or your estimate for not already loaded cells.)

```
fileprivate var heightForIndexPath = [NSIndexPath: CGFloat]()
fileprivate let averageRowHeight: CGFloat = 300 //your best estimate

//UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    heightForIndexPath[indexPath] = cell.frame.height
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return heightForIndexPath[indexPath] ?? averageRowHeight
}
```

(HUGE thanks to eyuelt for the insight that estimated row height is used to determine the new offset.)

Comment: Still have the same problem even with the cached approach.

Comment: This was a quick and simple solution to the problem for me. No amount of over or under-estimating the cell height seemed to work consistently. I also cleared the cache when the table was reloaded with new data.

Answer (score 0):

OBJ-C version of Daniel's answer:

```
//rowHeightForIndexPath is an NSMutableDictionary
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.rowHeightForIndexPath setObject:@(cell.frame.size.height) forKey:indexPath];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *cachedHeight = [self.rowHeightForIndexPath objectForKey:indexPath];

    return cachedHeight ? cachedHeight.floatValue : UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```